# Slicing array based on date condition

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, date, slice

I have an array of objects with a `Date` property. The array is sorted in descending Date order, i.e element at index 0 is the newest and the last element is the oldest. For example: `Array[0] = 2017-11-05`, `Array[1] = 2017-11-04`

From this array, I want to create an Array that contains Arrays with objects based on what day of the month is the closing date. For example if the closing date is the 6th day of each month:

```
Array = [2017-11-07, 
         2017-11-06, 
         2017-11-05, 
         2017-11-04]
```

should produce

```
NewArray = [[2017-11-07, 
             2017-11-06], 
            [2017-11-05, 
             2017-11-04]]
```

I have written my algorithm(I wont post it here because its long and full of `if and else` statements) based on all the different scenarios I could think of. For example, if two adjacent elements in the list are in the same month, I check if the first elements day is >= closing day and the second elements day is < closing date. Then there are cases where one of the elements are one month ahead, or several months ahead. Oh and there is also the cases where there is a year difference between the two, and that screws up the other conditions.

I am completely stuck as I'm testing my algorithm with edge cases. As I keep on going, I come up with more and more edge cases and the amount of `if and else` statements seems to go towards infinity. Is there a different approach to this, because I can't figure out how to write the algorithm without a ton of `if and else` conditions.

**EDIT:**
More problematic case.

```
Array = [2018-01-06, 
         2017-12-07, 
         2017-12-05, 
         2017-12-04,
         2017-11-16,
         2017-11-05,
         2017-09-27,
         2017-02-08,
         2016-12-07]
```

Desired output if the closing date is the 6th:

```
NewArray = [[2018-01-06], 
            [2017-12-07], 
            [2017-12-05, 
             2017-12-04,
             2017-11-16],
            [2017-11-05],
            [2017-09-27],
            [2017-02-08],
            [2016-12-07]]
```

This case for example, requires the algorithm to begin a new list where the month differnce is >= 2. In the cases where the month difference is 1, i.e one month apart, it has to check if one of the elements day is >= closing date (and) the other elements day is < closing date. In the cases where the elements are in the same month, it needs to check if one of the elements day is >= closing date and the other elements day < closing date. Just those conditions alone will not work well when there are elements in the list with different year.

Comment: Could you clarifiy by adding it to your example the cases with different months/year gap between samples?

Comment: This sounds easy, and the data set you showed is simple. Can you show a more problematic data set?

Comment: @Larme Updated the post with a more problematic case.

Comment: @matt Updated the post with a more problematic case.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just dense. What's the desired output for your second data set? Isn't it just that every date within a fiscal year goes into the same subarray? The problem has nothing to do with what is adjacent to what. You just look to see whether we're in the same fiscal year we were already in. Using date intervals, that's very easy. If not, could you show the desired output? Perhaps I'm not understand the problem.

Comment: @matt I added the desired output. Basically, every sub array should only contain objects with a date that is within the range of month.closingDay - month+1.closingDay. To know when we need to begin a new list, we need to compare the element before. I hope I explain it correctly, if not the desired output I added should clarify it.

Comment: @matt This is almost as if we would seperate the list by months. All dates in the same month would go into one sub array, and so on with the other months. But I need to do this with a specific day of the month. Instead of November - December, November 6th - December 6th. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah. So it's fiscal months, not fiscal years. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the `Calendar` method

- [`nextDate(after:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy:direction:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293473-nextdate)

is what you are looking for. It allows you to compute the 6th day
of a month which occurs before a given date. Then compare each 
date against the next current closing date, and either append
it to the current slice, or start a new slice and compute the next
(i.e. previous in time) closing date:

```
let yourDates: [Date] = ... // Your array of dates (in descending order)

let matchComponents = DateComponents(day: 6)
let cal = Calendar.current

var nextClosingDate = Date.distantFuture // So that the first date will start a new slice
var slicedDates: [[Date]] = []

for date in yourDates {
    if date >= nextClosingDate {
        // Append to current slice:
        slicedDates[slicedDates.count - 1].append(date)
    } else {
        // Start new slice and compute next closing date:
        slicedDates.append([date])
        nextClosingDate = cal.nextDate(after: date,
                                       matching: matchComponents,
                                       matchingPolicy: .nextTime,
                                       direction: .backward)!
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, except I was going to recommend using [DateInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateinterval). Probably even simpler.

Comment: This works. Now I have to learn why it works but thats another story. Thank you, I knew there had to be an another way of doing it instead of my long ugly messy code full of conditions. This was so much easier.. Have a great day!

Comment: [`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2919592-init) also seems like a pretty viable way to approach this

Comment: @Alexander Can you elaborate how this could be implemented?

Comment: @BartekSpitza Subtract the cutoff day from each date, and then group by the month of the resulting date. If you want a 2D array like what you have, then you can `dict.values.flatmap{$0}`